# How to remove a speed boost from someone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create a map and there is a speed boost but I want to know how to take away a speed boost from a player, or is this not possible

Comment: You can't really take it away, but you can override it with a speed boost of 0.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an effect command with a time of 0, for example `/effect @p minecraft:speed 0`, or you could use `/effect @p clear`.

The first one has the advantage of only clearing the speed effect. In both cases, replace the player selector `@p` if you don't want to target the nearest player.